# Can not resolve Symbol "ForSqliteHasDefaultValueSql"

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I want to define a Timestamp in my EF Core Project with SQLite and wanted to use this function:

[Click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlitepropertybuilderextensions.forsqlitehasdefaultvaluesql?view=efcore-1.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_SqlitePropertyBuilderExtensions_ForSqliteHasDefaultValueSql_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_PropertyBuilder_System_String_)

I know that this function seems to be in the classic EF and maybe it is not available anymore but 3 days ago I found the right package and the extension method that I was searching. Unfortunatelly I had another problem with the code and reverted everything and now I do not find the right package anymore. It was during a hackathon during the last hours, so i really do not remember how I got it to work :/

Does anybody know which nuget package has this method? The only thing that I am referencing is `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`. I allready tried the .Core and the classic EF dependencies and some random third party sqlite/ef packages, but I still can not compile this extension method :(

Comment: What EF Core version are you using?

Comment: I am using the 2.1.14 or something like this, you where right, the version was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the link, this method [applies to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlitepropertybuilderextensions.forsqlitehasdefaultvaluesql?view=efcore-1.1#applies-to) EF Core versions 1.0 and 1.1.

Starting from v2.0, most of the provider specific `ForAbcXyz` methods have been replaced with the generic `Xyz` methods.

So the method you are looking for is [HasDefaultValueSql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalpropertybuilderextensions.hasdefaultvaluesql?view=efcore-2.1). If you support multiple databases, use it inside a block enclosed with

```
if (Database.IsSqlite())
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: ok, maybe this was the method I found ;) I just tried it and it compiles, but the row version does not get created, when I update the row. But maybe this is something else. Does this work with sqlite and sqlserver together without any problems? (if i use the if, of course)

Comment: How are you supposed to do that inside an implementation of `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>` ?

Comment: @IsaacLlopis If you mean the `Database.IsSqlite()`, that's a good question for EF Core designers! I guess if you need something like that, you could pass `Database` to your `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>` implementing class and store it in a class member in order to have access t o it inside `Configure` method. But that's just a though, if you think I'm a part of the EF Core team, I am not, so "don't kill the messenger" :)